# How to switch the EF core Tracking behavior for the same LINQ query?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In my API project, I have several LINQ queries.

In some cases/business operations, I need to run these queries for read-only purposes. In other cases, I need to track entities returned by these queries, perform some data operations, and update the entities.

In my code, I want to define the queries only once, I don't want to duplicate them.

For read-only operations I want to use AsNoTracking() to improve the performance of the API request. If I use AsNoTracking() in queries, it will always be a non-tracking query, and when I want to update entities, it won't track them. I want to switch tracking behavior depending on the type of operation. (e.g. do not track for Get operation, track for PUT/PATCH operation). I can always define the same query twice, one with AsNoTracking and the other with Tracking, but I don't want to do that if you know the DRY principle.

Another option is to set  Context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior with appropriate value at the start of the operation but I am using AddDbContextPool() to reuse DB context instances.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are doing preemptive optimisation. If you do not return 1K rows, `AsNoTracking` will not give you super benefit. Also if you use `Select` or `ProjectTo` in queries - tracking is disabled, which is common behaviour for API because exposing data model to the world Is a bad idea.

Comment: How/where are you defining your queries "only once"? If you have a method to build a query, consider adding something like an `isReadOnly` flag which adds `.AsNoTracking()` to the query.

Comment: @Steve Py - How do you conditionally add .AsNoTracking() in the LINQ query expression ?

Comment: If you put LINQ queries in the methods like `IQueryable<Product> GetSomeProducts(...)`, you can always add `AsNoTracking` before materialization.

Comment: `IQueryable` is composed, so you can do something like `var query = context.Orders.Include(x => x.Customer).Where(x => x.OrderDate >= startDate); if (endDate.HasValue) query = query.Where(x => x.EndDate <= endDate.Value); if (isReadOnly) query = query.AsNoTracking(); var orders = await query.ToListAsync();`  That kind of thing, obviously with better formatting. :)